# Using an Android library that extends AppCompatDialog

Tags: nativescript

So I'm trying to create a plugin that uses PrettyDialog (https://github.com/mjn1369/PrettyDialog) using the latest NativeScript seed.

However I've run into the following error when compiling:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

That happens using the following code, and calling `show()` (TypeScript):

```
export class PrettyAlert {
  show() {
    const alert = this.createAlert();
  }

  createAlert(width?: number) {
    return new libs.mjn.prettydialog.PrettyDialog(app.android.context);
  }
}
```

I've been looking into the error here (pure Android): [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)
But none of the solutions have worked.

I figure it possible somehow, but I'm new a plugin building, and I'm sure there's some quirks I need to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are similar plugins - [fancyalert](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert) / [cfalert](https://github.com/shiv19/nativescript-cfalert-dialog) already if you are not very choosy about PrettyDialog.

NativeScript introduced support for **AppCompatActivity** from v5.x which seems just hit live. You should bypass this error if you upgrade to latest version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give v5 a go